# Can a Node package require a DB connection?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

As per the title, can a Node.js package require a database connection?

For example, I have written a specific piece of middlware functionality that I plan to publish via NPM, however, it requires a connection to a NoSQL database. The functionality in its current state uses Mongoose to save data in a specific format and returns a boolean value.

Is this considered bad practice?

Comment: Of course it can, why would you think it's bad practise? If that's how your middleware works then that's how it works, a good readme always helps. FWIW it might be useful to automatically create a default connection if one isn't passed, minimum requirement would be DB config.

Answer (score 0):

It is not a bad practice as long as you require the DB needed and also explicitly state it clearly in your **Readme.md** file, it's only a bad practice when you go ahead and work without provide a comment in your codes or a **readme.md** file that will guide any other person going through your codes.

Example:

```
//require your NoSQL database eg MongoDB
const mongoose = require('mongoose');


// to connect to the database. **boy** is the database name
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/boy', function(err) {
   if (err) {
       console.log(err);
   } else {
       console.log("Success");
   }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You generally have two choices when your module needs a database and wants to remain as independently useful as possible:

1. You can load a preferred database in your code and use it.
2. You can provide the developer using your module a means of passing in a database that meets your specification to be used by your module.  The usual way of passing in the database would be for the developer using your module to pass your module the data in a module constructor function.

In the first case, you may need to allow the developer to specify a disk store path to be used.  In the second case, you have to be very specific in your documentation about what kind of database interface is required.

There's also a hybrid option where you offer the developer the option of configuring and passing you a database, but if not provided, then you load your own.

> The functionality in its current state uses Mongoose to save data in a specific format and returns a boolean value. Is this considered bad practice?

No, it's not a bad practice.  This would be an implementation of option number 1 above.  As long as your customers (the developers using your module) don't mind you loading and using Mongoose, then this is perfectly fine.